# Passing date functions to javascript in laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I am getting some data using ajax but I cannot pass diffForHuman() function to get different format of date. I want date in another format. But by passing `created_at` to my markup then it is giving me undefined date. Below is my code. Pls help

//Javascript

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
        });

        $('select[name="class_id"]').on('change', function() {
            var classID = $(this).val();
            if(classID) {

                $.ajax({

                    url: '/attendance/ajax/'+classID,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {

                        var markup = '';
                        markup += '<tr><th style="width: 2%" class="align-middle text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="options"></th><th style="width: 2%" class="align-middle text-center">#</th> <th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Student ID<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Student Name<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Attendance<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%" class="text-center">Date<input type="text" class="form-control" disabled></th> <th style="width: 15%;" class="align-middle text-center">Actions</th> <tr>';

                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {

                            markup += '<tr> <td><input class="checkBoxes" type="checkbox" name="checkBoxArray[]"></td> <td><input type="hidden" value="'+value.id+'" name="id[]">' + value.id + '</td> <td><input type="hidden" value="'+value.student_id+'" name="student_id[]">' + value.student_id + '</td> <td><input type="hidden" value="'+value.first_name+'" name="first_name[]"><input type="hidden" value="'+value.last_name+'" name="last_name[]">' + value.first_name+ ' '  + value.last_name +  '<td><input type="hidden" value="'+value.attendance+'" name="attendance[]">' + value.attendance + '</td>' +  '<td><input type="hidden" value="'+value.created_at+'" name="created_at[]">' + value.created_at + '</td>' + '<td style=" width=12%" class="text-center"> <a><button title="Edit" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><span class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></span></button></a> </td>' +  '</td> <tr>';

                        });
                        $('table[id="studentsData"]').html(markup);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

//Controller

```
 public function student_attendance_registers() {
        $attendances = StudentsAttendance::all();
        $classes = StudentsClass::pluck('class_name', 'id')->all();

        return view('admin.students.attendance.student_attendance_registers', compact('attendances', 'classes'));
    }




 //Model

    class StudentsAttendance extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [
            'class_id',
            'student_id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'attendance'
        ];

        public function studentsClass() {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\StudentsClass');
        }

        public function getdateForHumansAttribute()
        {
            return $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
        }

        public function toArray()
        {
            $data = parent::toArray();

            $data['diffForHumans'] = $this->diffForHumans;

            return $data;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you show us your controller function?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this, would be to add a `getdateForHumanAttribute` method:

```
public function getdateForHumansAttribute()
{
    return $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
}
```

Then on your model you can use anywhere:

```
$model->dateForHumans;
```

For an easy way to always add `dateForHumans` attribute when you retrieve this model, add it to `toArray` method:

*(Also on your model)*

```
public function toArray()
{
    $data = parent::toArray();

    $data['diffForHumans'] = $this->diffForHumans;

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: But how i will pass that method to the markup i had written  for my table in the above javascript

Comment: If you add that `toArray()` method, every time you retreive data from your model, that method is called, adding `'diffForHumans'` to your array, you'll be able to access it on your javascript.

Comment: So you mean that I need to add those two methods in my controller ?

Comment: Yes, if you add those methods, whenever you retrieve data from Database *using your model*, `diffForHumans` will be added.

Comment: Ok but pls check my markup above in the javascript. How i can call it there ? Because it give me error when i try to call it there

Comment: I updated the answer, so now I'm using `created_at` on `function getdateForHumansAttribute()`, in your view, instead of calling `created_at`, call `value.diff_for_humans`

Comment: I added this `getdateForHumansAttribute()` in my controller and `toArray()` method in my model and call value.diff_for_humans in the markup but now it giving me Undefined date

Comment: @HasnainKahn you are almost there, it's not `date` you should use `created_at` on the `getdateForHumansAttribute()` function.

Comment: What do you mean **you should use created_at on the getdateForHumansAttribute() function** by this. I copied your updated answer. And now **value.diff_for_humans** I tried this which is giving me undefined date and applying created_at giving me the same result from database. What will be the solution sir ?

Comment: @HasnainKahn I updated my answer one more time, now it should work

Comment: I updated my question according to your suggestions. Please check it out now. Tell me if something is wrong. Check my markup in the javascript code where i am passing `created_at`

Comment: @HasnainKahn, what method, in the controller, does this call: `url: '/attendance/ajax/'+classID,`? Can you add it to your question?

Comment: Thats  a selector dropdown for classes in the view. And in the controller I just added this  `$classes = StudentsClass::pluck('class_name', 'id')->all();`

Comment: Nothing more happens than that